# Little confusion dealing with docker desktop's daemon.json

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, docker-daemon

I need to edit my docker daemon's config, and from what I'm readong there are 2(?) that I 'can' use?

**One path:**

```
C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json
```

**Other path:**

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\windows-daemon-options.json
```

**First question:**

- The `windows-daemon-options.json` already exists and has data in it (*more on that below*)
- The `daemon.json` doesn't exist; I'd have to create it

So, do I just edit the `windows-daemon-options.json`, or do I create the `daemon.json`, and either just do in my edits, and then on daemon startup it'll sort of use the former as the "base" config and overwrite just the settings added with the latter? OR do I copy/paste ALL of the settings from the former to the latter, edit what I need, and then upon startup it'll use the regular `daemon.json` as the preferred config (sort of as if the former were a sample config)?

**Second Question:**

The data in `windows-daemon-options.json` has a lot of "redacted" in it, I'm wondering how that all figures into all of this?

**i.e. here's the data in it (literally):**

```
{
    "allow-nondistributable-artifacts": ["host_port_or_cidr|redacted"],
    "authorization-plugins": [],
    "bridge": "",
    "cluster-advertise": "",
    "cluster-store": "",
    "data-root": "path|redacted",
    "debug": true,
    "default-ulimits": {},
    "disable-legacy-registry": false,
    "dns": ["ip|redacted"],
    "dns-opts": [],
    "dns-search": ["domain|redacted"],
    "exec-opts": [],
    "experimental": true,
    "fixed-cidr": "redacted",
    "graph": "deprecated|redacted",
    "group": "",
    "hosts": ["endpoint|redacted"],
    "insecure-registries": ["host_port_or_cidr|redacted"],
    "labels": [],
    "live-restore": true,
    "log-driver": "",
    "log-level": "",
    "max-concurrent-downloads": 3,
    "max-concurrent-uploads": 5,
    "metrics-addr":"endpoint|redacted",
    "mtu": 0,
    "pidfile": "redacted",
    "raw-logs": false,
    "registry-mirrors": ["registry|redacted"],
    "shutdown-timeout": 15,
    "storage-driver": "",
    "storage-opts": [],
    "swarm-default-advertise-addr": "endpoint|redacted",
    "tlscacert": "redacted",
    "tlscert": "redacted",
    "tlskey": "redacted",
    "tlsverify": true
}
```

Hopefully I was able to clearly convey my questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start Docker Desktop in Windows container mode, if `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json` does not exist, it will get created with some default values.
You can create it beforehand or edit it afterwards (and restart Docker Desktop).

Or you can use the UI (Settings / Docker Engine), which validates the changes.
`C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\windows-daemon-options.json` is the schema internal file used for validation there, you probably don’t want to change it.

See also https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#docker-engine

Comment: Interesting; turns out I have a `daemon.json` at: `C:\Users\<username>\.docker\daemon.json` that it looks like got created when I entered in some stuff in the GUI.

Comment: That’s for the Linux container mode daemon.

Answer (score 9):

`C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json` is for windows containers, this is the default location in windows daemon code.

`C:\Users\<username>\.docker\daemon.json` is for linux containers, this hyper-v/wls2/linux native default location.

Those 2 files are created when the corresponding daemon starts the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Just:

1. Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type: `%userprofile%\.docker\`
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>